# Rails 4.1 "Password can't be blank" ...again

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm getting back into RoR development, so I'm playing a bit of catch up with 4.X. I'm running Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1.1 with RVM. I've seen this question asked several times and implemented all of the solutions I've found but am still getting "Password can't be blank" message. Below is my code. I'm hoping that someone has seen this problem and know the answer.

==============

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController

def signup
  @user = User.new()
end


def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
   redirect_to :action => "signup_success"
  else
   render :action => "signup"
  end
end


def signup_success
end


private
    def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :screenname, :email, :postal_code, :password,:password_confirmation)
   end
end
```

==========

```
require 'digest/sha2'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

def password=(pass)
    unless pass.blank?
        salt = [Array.new(6){rand(256).chr}.join].pack("m").chomp
        self.password_salt, self.password_hash = salt, Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(pass + salt)
end
end

end
```

============

```
<div class='row'>
    <h6>Sign-Up NOW!</h6>
    <div class='c5'>
    <%= form_for @user, as: :user, method: :post, url: register_create_path(@user), :html => {:class => 'hform'}  do |f| %>

        <%= f.label 'firstname','First name'%><%= f.text_field :firstname, :required => true , :class => 'required'%>
        <%= f.label 'lastname','Last name' %> <%= f.text_field :lastname, :required => true, :class => 'required' %>
        <%= f.label 'email','Email'%> <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true, :class => 'required'%>
        <label>Postal Code</label><%= f.text_field :postal_code, :required => true, :class => 'required' %>
        <hr>
        <%= f.label 'screenname','Username'%><%= f.text_field :screenname, :required => true, :class => 'required'  %>
        <%= f.label 'password', 'Password'%> <%= f.password_field 'password', :required => true, :class => 'required' %>
        <%= f.label 'password_confirmation','Confirm Password'%><%= f.password_field 'password_confirmation', :required => true, :class => 'required'%>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
        <p class='text-center'><%=f.submit "Create Account"%></p>

    <%end%>
</div>

</div>
```

===========

Comment: Instead of adding "solved problem" you should answer your own question and accept your answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'has_secure_password' includes some validations. You just need to add an option, like the one below, after it.

```
has_secure_password validataions: false
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED PROBLEM

I removed Bcrypt and "has_secure_password" from my User model. That resolved my problem. I updated my code below just in case someone runs into the same problem."password" and "password_confirmation" are filtered on submission of the form data.